# Ad integration for Winforms application in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I had been searching the Web for a while, trying to find a solution. But all that I found about Ad integration is for mobile apps and I cannot find a solution for Windows application.

My question is - **Is there a way to make a popup Ad in Winforms application, and of course receive some money from (clicking or viewing or whatever, I don't know how this is actually works) on it?**

For now I have written (I actually downloaded it) a method that shows a Taskbar Notification like Skype, and I loop it in BackgroundWorker with a delay of 2 min and then i have no idea what to do next. How to attach Ad to that notification? What and how  it is supposed to be attached to my Paypal account in order to receive money from clicking, viewing.

I will be very grateful if you guys would help me to understand all aspects. PS. I am surprised,there is nothing on the Web regarding information on how to integrate Ad in Winforms application. Weird, it could be very handy.

Comment: You might have the click event associated with whatever popup trigger the OS to open whatever web link leading to PayPal or an affiliate link or whatever. For PayPal you could follow their example of the links behind their "donate" buttons and customize it with your info.

Comment: @DarthContinent PayPal linking is not a problem, ad integration into desktop apps is the problem and not only Winforms...

Answer (score 1):

Well there are many ways that you can put ads in a Windows Form, but someone must provide you the ads that you will get money from.

Get an affiliate account at some trustful website make a html file with the ads inside and uploaded it some server.
Then in Windows Forms make a new Form with a web browser inside of it, point the browser to the uploaded html file and you can use different kind of events even Task Scheduler to initiate the small app or code that will show the form with the ads.

I would recommend Gooogle AdSense but first read their Terms and make sure you follow them or they will terminate your account.

I just saw that this post is 3 months old but I already wrote the answer so...
Goodluck if you haven't found an answer by now.

Comment: Google Adsense TOS is against using it in an application - only ads on websites allowed.